# ¿Como filtrar en v-for de un input text, vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

Actualmente genero un listado mediante un arreglo de objetos de la siguiente forma:

```
<v-layout row wrap v-for="(noticia, index) in listado_noticias" :key="index">
          <v-flex xs12>
            <v-card color="with" class="black--text">
              <v-layout>
                <v-flex xs5>
                  <v-img
                    :src="noticia.imagen"
                    height="125px"
                    contain
                  ></v-img>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs7>
                  <v-card-title primary-title>
                    <div>
                      <div class="headline">{{noticia.titulo}}</div>
                      <div>{{noticia.resumen}}</div>
                    </div>
                  </v-card-title>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
              <v-divider light></v-divider>
              <v-card-actions class="pa-3">
                  <v-btn flat @click="leerNota(noticia)">Leer nota</v-btn>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
```

basicamente lo que necesito es poder filtrar ese listado anterior mediante lo que ingrese en este input text:

```
<v-layout>
          <v-flex xs12 md12>
            <v-text-field
              outline
              dark
              label="Buscar"
              v-model="searchText"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
```

arreglo:

```
listado_noticias:
[
{
id:111,
titulo: 'Titulo a filtrar',
resumen: 'resumen
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba utilizando un computed:

```
computed: {
    listado_noticias_filtered () {
        return this.listado_notificas.filter(item => item.include(this.searchText))
    }
}
```

En el template utiliza

```
<v-layout row wrap v-for="(noticia, index) in listado_noticias_filtered" :key="index">
```